# T-SQL Query works manually, but not in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a trigger on my database that I'm using to enforce a business rule: when a certain "event" happens, a flag on one of the tables is updated. I know this is not the suggested use of triggers, and the better thing to do would be to enforce this rule outside of the database, in the code that generates the event. But due to reasons outside of my control that is not possible and the maintenance of this flag falls to the database.

So, I designed the appropriate query to maintain this flag. The query goes something like this:

```
UPDATE flg_tbl
SET flag = 'T'
FROM flag_table AS flg_tbl
INNER JOIN table1 AS tbl1 ON tbl1.id = flg_tbl.id
INNER JOIN table2 AS tbl2 ON tbl2.id = flg_tbl.id
...
WHERE tbl2.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

When I run this query manually, everything works great. But as a trigger, nothing happens.

This trigger is to be executed after a stream of table inserts, which affect all of the inner join tables in the query. I put the trigger as an AFTER INSERT trigger on the last table that is updated in the list of tables, but still it doesn't work. I feel like the fact that it is being executed during this stream of inserts is the culprit; perhaps the tables all haven't been committed yet and the trigger is using old data, despite having been triggered.

Is there a way to delay the trigger until after the whole transaction has been committed? Or is it waiting until it's committed, and I'm just not seeing the real reason?

Full, obfuscated version of the query (X is the table to be updated, and I is the table that the trigger is on):

```
UPDATE X
SET X.flag = 'T'
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN tableX AS X ON X.otherrow = B.otherrow
INNER JOIN tableA AS A2 ON A.diffrow = A2.diffrow AND X.id = A2.id
INNER JOIN tableC AS C ON B.id = C.id AND C.otherflag = 'A'
INNER JOIN tableI AS I ON I.id = B.id
WHERE I.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

Comment: How can you run this manually? `inserted` doesn't exist outside the scope of a trigger.

Comment: On which of those tables did you put the trigger?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I replaced (SELECT id FROM inserted) with the id's that were inserted.

Comment: @hatchet I put the trigger on one of the inner join tables. There's 5 of them, and I put the trigger on the last one that is being inserted into by the outside code.

Comment: @Klazen108 - so a particular id value will have an entry in all those tables, in a column called Id in every one? What is the purpose of all the inner joins if they all join on flg_tbl.id when only flg_tbl is updated? My suspicion is that id columns are mixed up in the joins, and/or the `WHERE` clause is always returning false.

Comment: @hatchet They aren't all joined on the same id. There is a self join at one point, and a join on a different id at another point. Also, flg_tbl itself is not affected by the stream of inserts, it's being updated here, and the joins are to figure out which rows need to be updated. The query itself works outside of the trigger, so I don't think the query is the problem. You may have a point with the where clause, as that is the only difference between inside the trigger and outside.

Comment: @Klazen108 - I'm just going on the code you posted. If a single row from tableX is inserted with Id=12, then there must be a row in all the tables shown(Table1, Table2, and Flag_tbl) where the Id column in each table equals 12. If any of those tables don't, then nothing gets updated. That's why it seems to me they are joined on the same id. It would help if you showed the whole trigger, as well as all the table relationships including foreign key column names.

Comment: @hatchet I'm updating the question with the full layout of the query (yes, it's complex, and probably not in the best order to read, but it was repurposed from elsewhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing tableI (the one with the trigger) seems unnecessary, since its rows are in `inserted`. The following would seem to be equivalent, and may avoid the problem:

```
UPDATE X
SET X.flag = 'T'
FROM tableA AS A
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN tableX AS X ON X.otherrow = B.otherrow
INNER JOIN tableA AS A2 ON A.diffrow = A2.diffrow AND X.id = A2.id
INNER JOIN tableC AS C ON B.id = C.id AND C.otherflag = 'A'
WHERE B.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

or

```
UPDATE X
SET X.flag = 'T'
FROM tableX AS X
INNER JOIN tableB AS B ON X.otherrow = B.otherrow
INNER JOIN tableA AS A ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN tableA AS A2 ON A.diffrow = A2.diffrow AND X.id = A2.id
INNER JOIN tableC AS C ON B.id = C.id AND C.otherflag = 'A'
WHERE B.id IN (SELECT id FROM inserted)
```

Comment: That's it, it works now! I guess by referencing "tableI" in the trigger it was using the old data and failing there. I really appreciate your help!